# How many equilateral triangles can be inscribed in a triangle?

Tags: geometry

Given any triangle ABC find points D, E and F not A, B or C, where D is on segment AB, E on segment BC and F on segment CA, such that triangle DEF is equilateral.  How many such
 triangles exist?  I can construct at least 1.  I feel but cannot prove that there are no more than 3. Please  help.

Comment: I think this is more reasonable question after the edit, and I'm reopening your question.

Comment: In general, you should expect infinitely-many inscribed equilaterals. Certainly, if $\triangle ABC$ is itself equilateral, then any symmetrically-placed $D$, $E$, $F$ give equilateral $\triangle DEF$. Otherwise, conditions $|DE|=|EF|$ and $|DE|=|DF|$ lead to two equations in three unknowns, say, $|AD|$, $|BE|$, $|CF|$. ($|EF|=|DF|$ gives a dependent equation.) Thus, one unknown is "free" and can "usually" take on infinitely-many values in a range. (If there are *two* inscribed equilaterals, say for $D=D_1$ and $D=D_2$, then there's an inscribed equilateral for any $D$ between $D_1$ and $D_2$.)

Answer (score 1):

There's a reason you can't prove there are no more than three inscribed equilaterals:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It depends. Do you mean without overlapping? Must the triangle be completely covered by the equilateral triangles? Must the triangles be lying on the triangle simultaneously?

A particular case is if the given triangle is equilateral. You can see in the figure, depending what inscribed means, that we get $4$ equilateral triangles.

[image]

Comment: When "inscribed" means that all vertices of the inscribed triangle have to lie on the circumference of the given triangle, the answer is $\infty$: The given triangle has at least one angle $\leq60^\circ$, and it is then easy to inscribe small equilateral triangles with two vertices on one adjacent side and the third vertex on the other adjacent side.

Comment: if 'inscribed' means that the vertices of the inscribed triangle lie on the given triangle and none of the vertices are coincident with the vertices of the given triangle, then are you sure there are an infinite number?